# Hidden Input affects string data on HttpPost from View to Controller MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on MVC 5 with C#. I am trying to pass some data from a View to a Controller, using hidden input texts. 
On my View, I have this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <input type="text" name="Client_" hidden value=@clientName>
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

When I click on the Insert button, I receive the value of the Client_ input in the controller. It works perfectly if the value of `@clientName` is a string without spaces. For example if `@clientName` is equal to "Hola", I receive "Hola" on the controller HttpPost method. But if the value of the string contains spaces such as "Hola mundo", then I only receive "Hola".

I have used two way for receiving the data on the controller.

1. As a string parameter called as the hidden input.
2. Using Request object, like

   ```
   string test = Request["Client_"].ToString();
   ```

None of them work properly. I always get only the first word of the string.

Can some of you kindly tell me what is happening? 
Do I have a better way to transfer data from the Views to the Controllers

Comment: First you need to use `value="@clientName"` (quotes) which will solve the issue. But this code is dreadful practice. Create a model with a property `clientName` and pass the model to the view and use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.clientName)` and then post back the model (i.e. the POST method should have a parameter for the model. Never use `FormCollection`

Comment: A good way to debug this sort of thing is to View Source in your browser - then you'll see that the input looks like `<input type="text" name="Client_" hidden value=Hola>` and `<input type="text" name="Client_" hidden value=Hola mundo>` both without double quotes around the value.